# A younger generation of men follow or follows?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

Could you explain to me which is correct?

1. A younger generation of **men follow** . . .
2. A **younger generation** of men **follows** . . .

Could you also explain why?

I was thinking that the *bit* that cannot be removed should be the one that determines whether the verb is singular or plural. The sentence would lose its sense without *younger generation* so does that mean that that is the *bit* to which *follows* must correspond?

Comment: It is **generation** that follows, not *men*, so the second option is correct. Leave out *of men* and you'll see what must agree in the sentence (by the way, leave it out unless absolutely required by the context).

Going forward, please put more effort in your research.

Comment: @Mykola: This ('grammatical concord' or 'formal agreement' as the sub-classification is termed) is only one of the accepted (by some schools) ways of treating this issue. See http://www.odlt.org/ballast/grammatical_concord.html and notice that the word "incorrectly" is used there in scare quotes - incorrectly according to some prescriptive pseudo-rules but not in the opinion of many modern grammarians. 'A younger generation of' is a compound quantifier. Barrie's answer is far more balanced (and I'd say acceptable to modern scholarship). Going forward, please put more effort in your research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Absolutely agree with you. I will certainly try to put more effort, because it is only after reading Barrie's answer that I have gotten the notion of different agreement types, which kind of speaks volumes of the extent of my research.

Comment: @Mykola: Here's a neat synopsis (and a plug): http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22185&p=80604&hilit=synesis+notional#p80604 . Though there is a rule of thumb that "Americans tend to follow the 'logical rule' (synesis) less than Brits", there is **NO** Grammar Czar saying that one MUST adopt a certain convention in any given location.

Comment: The issue has been raised in various ways in earlier posts -- so much so it should now be considered GR on ELU.

Answer (score 5):

*Follows* shows formal agreement, *follow* shows notional and proximity agreement. The choice between the two depends on whether the speaker wants to emphasise *generation* as a unitary whole or as a collection of individuals.