# offers vs offer

Tags: verb-agreement

ABC is an online platform providing **technology and software** that **offer** XYZ and YXV with insights using environmental data.

In the sentence above, should it be phrased technology and software that **Offers** OR **Offer**?

Normal subject and verb agreement rules state that it should be offers, but it doesn't sound right. Can anyone explain what is the correct term to be used and why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your discomfort at the phrasing may be due to the tendency to apply [proximity agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/proximityagreement.htm). Have a look also at this question: [A younger generation of men follow or follows?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128613/a-younger-generation-of-men-follow-or-follows/128636#128636).

Comment: Twinning 'technology' with 'software' is a semantic stretch. Isn't there a classification error (eg 'She is an expert at dancing and waltzing', which admittedly is more clear-cut)? Not just nitpicking, because the 'unariness' (cohesiveness) of 'A and B' is in question here. _Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast_ but _Bacon and eggs are both hard to source at the moment_, using notional agreement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["One of the children who was" vs. "one of the children who were"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185714/one-of-the-children-who-was-vs-one-of-the-children-who-were) (antecedent of 'who' / 'that').

Answer (score 2):

It depends what is doing the offering.

If the platform is doing the offering, then the platform is singular so it **offers**.

If the technology and software are doing the offering, then they are plural and so they **offer**.

It's not clear to me which is the case.  A real sentence without XYZ etc might make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the sentence is "platform" so you should use offers.Anytime you come across this conundrum you should find the subject of the sentence. If the subject is singular, use offers; if the subject is plural, use offer.

Comment: Are you sure? What if it is the technology and software that is doing the offering?

Comment: XAPZ is a law firm well known to many companies that is/are often in trouble with the police.

Comment: 'John is one of the boys who play/s football', covered before.